# @RequestPart("json") as a property in ModelAttribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

is there a way to embed JSON object into model attribute in spring MVC?
For example on the client side :

```
var obj = JSON.parse(user); //user is a json string containing user object info
var formdata =  new FormData();
formdata.append("userInfo",obj);
```

on Server side :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/here", method = {
            RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET }, headers = "content-type=multipart/form-data")
    @ResponseBody
    public String doSomething(
    @ModelAttribute MyForm myForm,
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response
    ) {
User user = myForm.getUserInfo();
}
```

Comment: Not a built-in way, no. Why do you want to do this? Just send full JSON in the body of the request.

Comment: There are more params along with userInfo that's already out there in myForm, so here userInfo is the new param that needs to be appended to existing list of params which are part of an exisiting modelattribute

Comment: can I just access via @RequestPart on serverside?